# how to fit content in browse height

Tags: jquery, html, css, window, height

i want make contentarea height browser window hight but minus top and bottom div height also so then i will be fit in properly. i already did some via jquery but i am always 15px extra height. any idea how i can fix that.

may be can direct put px in js or may be just minus 15px more.

demo http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/1y06jssp/

bellow is js. it minus from class **topbar** and **topbar2** but still i am getting 15px more space.

```
 $(window).on('resize', function(){

        var h = $(this).height() - $('.topbar').height() - $('.topbar2').height();
        if(h<=400) h=400
        $('.contentarea').height(h); 


    }).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: border and margins is what you need to look at

Comment: @pagol where is topbar2 class?

Comment: Check this if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/1y06jssp/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the padding added to the topbar is what is appending the extra pixels so just take out the padding or change it up to your fit

```
.topbar {
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border-top: solid 3px #0b0b0b;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 56px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1y06jssp/1/)

Comment: thank u.. i remove padding and border. now it fine. thanks